# How would I create a triangle & triangle inverse pattern in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

What steps do I need to follow to make triangle patterns in pinescript, how are they formed?

I’ve tried, searching up online, mainly YouTube. I was expecting to find a video that showed how to create it with the zigzag Lines.

Answer (score 1):

TradingView has a [built in chart patterns](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/new-indicators-chart-patterns-29191/) you can use. Add an indicator and search for "Triangle Chart Pattern"

Comment: Yes I’ve seen that, but I want to create a script for it yk, pretty much like that one. I want to see the code and learn from it.